# ggplot2: color part of the line

Tags: r, ggplot2

I stumble. I need your advice and suggestions. I need to apply different scheme for the part of the lines - color, dashed or increase the thickness for "very_important_features". I need to make them visually more appealing.

```
dat <- rbind(
x <- sort(sample(1:1000,size = 200) + sample(1:500,size = 200, replace = T)),
y <- sort(sample(1:1000,size = 200) + sample(1:200,size = 200, replace = T)),
z <- sort(sample(1:1000,size = 200) - sample(1:100,size = 200, replace = T)))
rownames(dat) <- c("x","y","z")
#colnames(dat) <- paste("feature",1:200,sep="_")
library(reshape)
dat.m <- melt(dat)
ggplot(data=dat.m, aes(x=X2, y=value, group=X1, color = X1)) + geom_line()
very_important_features <- unique(sort(sample(dat.m$X2, 100)))
```

Answer (score 6):

It's generally better practice to identify the thing you want to plot as a separate column in the data, so that it can be *mapped* to the plot aesthetics/layers. Here is an example:

1 - add variable to data frame:

```
dat.m$important <- ifelse(dat.m$X2 < 60, "yes","no")
```

2 - Plot, using that variable as the thing that controls size

```
ggplot(data=dat.m)+
  aes(x=X2, y=value, group=X1, color = X1, size=important) +
  geom_line()+
  scale_size_manual(values=c("yes"=3, "no"=1))
```

Here's the output:
[image: plot with line size mapped to data frame variable]

and now there's a handy legend showing you what line size means.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit unsure what part you want to make stand out more, but here is one suggestion:

```
ggplot(data=dat.m, aes(x=X2, y=value, group=X1, color = X1)) + 
  geom_line() +
  geom_line(data = dat.m[very_important_features, ], size = 2)
```

[image]